# Multiple DataSources across 2 components

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, datasource

I have 2 Spring Boot applications **App1** and **App2**. **App2** can run as a standalone application and also is embedded in application **App1** as a dependency. I want **App1** to be able to make calls to services of **App2** which makes repo calls to a different DB. I have configured DataSource beans in both components as follows:

**App1**

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ev.app1.repositories",
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "app1EntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "app1TransactionManager")
  public class PersistenceApp1Configuration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource.app1")
    public DataSourceProperties app1DataSourceProperties() {
      return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "app1DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource.app1")
    public DataSource tmDataSource() {
      return tmDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
      .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }
```

App1 application.properties:

```
app.datasource.app1.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mercury_tmdb?currentSchema=txm
app.datasource.app1.username=postgres
app.datasource.app1.password=root
app.datasource.app1.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**App2**

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ev.app1.repositories",
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "app1EntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "app1TransactionManager")
  public class PersistenceApp1Configuration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource.app1")
    public DataSourceProperties app1DataSourceProperties() {
      return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "app2DataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource.app2")
    public DataSource app2DataSource() {
    return tmDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
      .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }
```

App2 application.properties:

```
app.datasource.app2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mercury_cldb?currentSchema=led
app.datasource.app2.username=postgres
app.datasource.app2.password=root
app.datasource.app2.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

As you can see, I had to mark the DataSource bean in **App2** as @Primary to override the default spring datasource. But the same I cannot do for **App1** since it already has a Primary bean from **App2**. Any work around for this? Or may be I am completely off with this approach?

Note: I have other config beans which I haven't shown here but I can share if required

Comment: How are you using the datasources? are you telling your data access services to use some specific or are you just using the default config from Spring?

Comment: @WilliamAndrésBernal I have added the property file from where its fetching the db information

Comment: I try to put my question better. How does a service knows which datasource has to be used? do you have any configuration in your code for this or you just let spring to do its job?

Comment: I used @EnableJpaRepositories to set the packages to scan, EMF and TM. I hope that answers your question. Edited the question as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, both the services are in the same source code repository?. If so, you can use spring profile to create a datasource based on the application.  https://www.intertech.com/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/

Comment: Thanks @WilliamAndrésBernal it was just what I was looking for. ```@ConditionalOnExpression``` was better suited for my use case though. Can you post this as answer so I can mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional bean configuration from Spring, so you can decide when to use each datasource.

You can use the annotation like this:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression(value = "${module.enabled} and ${module.submodule.enabled}")
```

depending on your specific configuration.